# Changing variable when method is called

Tags: java

I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find an answer to this. I am trying to increment a variable every time a method is called but it seems to be resetting the variable and only increment it once. Here is the code I have. So the object is to change the `Bicycle` constructor to add 1 to the `bicycleCount` each time a new object of type `Bicycle` is created. The issue I am having is it resets to 0 each time so I keep getting `Bike` 1 for each bike I create.

```
class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two instances each of MountainBike and RoadBike.
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle.MountainBike();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle.MountainBike();
        Bicycle bike3 = new Bicycle.RoadBike();
        Bicycle bike4 = new Bicycle.RoadBike();

        // Invoke methods on those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        System.out.println("Bike: " + bike1.getbicycleCount());
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        System.out.println("Bike: " + bike2.getbicycleCount());
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
// Change the Bicycle class to be an abstract class.
abstract class Bicycle {
    /* Add a private variable of type integer named bicycleCount, and initialize
    this variable to 0.*/
    private static int bicycleCount=0;
    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    /* Change the Bicycle constructor to add 1 to the bicycleCount each time a
    new object of type Bicycle is created. */
    Bicycle() {
        bicycleCount++;
    }



    // Add a public getter method to return the current value of bicycleCount.
    public int getbicycleCount() {
        return bicycleCount;
    }

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
        cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed = speed + increment;
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
        System.out.println("cadence:" +
                cadence + " speed:" +
                speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }

    /* Derive two classes from Bicycle: MountainBike and RoadBike. To the
MountainBike class, add the private variables tireTread (String) and
mountainRating (int). To the RoadBike class, add the private variable
maximumMPH (int). */
    static class MountainBike extends Bicycle {
        private String tireTread;
        private int mountainRating;
    }
    static class RoadBike extends Bicycle {
        private int maximumMPH;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this class used? It's abstract so it must be extended by some other class.

Comment: decleare `bycicleCount` as `static`, and it should work.

Comment: Here is the output I am getting.

Comment: Bike: 4
cadence:50 speed:10 gear:2
Bike: 4
cadence:40 speed:20 gear:3

Answer (score 3):

You want a single count for the entire `Bicycle` class. Make the counter `static`.

```
private static int bicycleCount = 0;
```

If you need it to be thread-safe, you should probably change the `int` to an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use static counter as this will mark field as class level instead of instance level.

For thread seafty use Atomic classes